# Classification of compact multiplication operators

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

It is known, that if $A_\phi:L_2[0,1] \to L_2[0,1]$  - multiplication operator defined as $(A_\phi x)(t)=\phi(t) \cdot x(t)$ is compact $\Rightarrow$ $\phi = 0$ $a.e.$  I wonder if this is also true for $A_\phi:L_2[0,1] \to L_1[0,1]$, where $A_\phi$ is defined the same way.

Comment: To be clear, you are talking about $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $L^1(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: First we need to clarify the context. For example, what you say is known is not true for counting measure. Regarding the question about $L^2\to L^1$, have you tried simply imitating the _proof_ for $L^2\to L^2$? The more or less obvious proof I have in mind  seems to me to work with no significant changess...

Comment: Corrected the conditions of the task, forgot to specify the space $X$ of $L_2(X)$

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I proved statement for case $A_\phi: L_2[0,1] \to L_2[0,1]$ by contradiction with invertibility of the operator $A_\phi|_{X'}$  where X' is support of $\phi$. In the case that interests me such a proof does not work as $A_\phi|_{X'}$ is not onto $L_1(X')$.

Comment: Then maybe you should start by looking for  a correct proof of the $L^2\to  L^2$ case. $A_\phi|_{X'}$ is not invertible. (There was a sketch of the simple proof in a comment  here that seems to have disappeared - if you can still see it it's worth reading...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich unfortunately the comment disappeared from me too.